# "Call to undefined function" error when calling member function from constructor

Tags: php

Well this is depressing, but probably some little oversight I imagine.

I have this PHP class:

```
class SearchModel
{
    private $searchOptions;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->searchOptions = populateSearchOptions();
    }

    public function getSearchOption()
    {
        return $this->searchOptions;
    }

    private function populateSearchOptions()
    {
        $this->searchOptions = array(
            // values....
        );
    }
}
```

When I instantiate this class, PHP returns:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function populateSearchOptions() in SearchModel.php ...
```

When changing:

```
$this->searchOptions = populateSearchOptions();
```

to:

```
$this->searchOptions = $this->populateSearchOptions();
```

the complaint is gone but the contents of `$searchOptions` is `NULL`.

So... if I call `populateSearchOptions()` this way from inside the constructor, instantiate the class and try to output the contents of the array:

```
$this->model = new SearchModel();
// Output contents of model->searchOptions
```

The output is NULL. But when I do (and not bother trying to call `populateSearchOptions()` from the constructor):

```
$this->model = new SearchModel();
$this->model->populateSearchOptions();
// Output contents of $this->model->searchOptions
```

It outputs the values assigned to `$this->model->searchOptions` as desired.

Anyone know what's going on here? I'd like to simply be able to call `populateSearchOptions()` from the `SearchModel` constructor.

Comment: Unless I've lost my mind, you must *always* use the `$this->` syntax when calling member functions in PHP (as well as accessing member variables).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the constructor from

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->searchOptions = populateSearchOptions();
}
```

to

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->populateSearchOptions();
}
```

1) always use `$this` in php to call non static class methods and variables

2)The result was null before because the `populateSearchOptions` function does not return a value so you were effectively setting a value to it in the function then setting it to `null` immediately after.

alternatively you can change the `populateSearchOptions` function to

```
private function populateSearchOptions()
{
    return array(
        // values....
    );
}
```

and do effectively the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, I left out a detail. I have a get function that returns the array. That's how I'm getting it after creating a SearchModel object. I've updated the question to include this.

Comment: The constructor is setting the instance variable to `NULL` due to the lack of a return by the populateSearchOptions function

Answer (score 0):

> Output contents of model->searchOptions is NULL

it is null because it is a private variable

try making the searchOptions public then it will be good:

```
class SearchModel
{
    public $searchOptions;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->searchOptions = $this->populateSearchOptions();
    }

    private function populateSearchOptions()
    {
        $this->searchOptions = array(
            // values....
        );
    }
}
```